# LiveWallpaper service doesn't stop

Tags: android, service, andengine, live-wallpaper

My livewallpaper refuses to unload itself once I choose to set other LWP or even restart my LWP after it. Result: it crashes with out of memory error on second or third reload, as it trying to load again and again an 16Mb texture in the same heap.

In DDMS I see that my service is still alive after other LWP was chosen, despite all of that onDestroy() and other events were called. I've tried to call stopSelf(), bunch of actual resource unload methods, but it does nothing - service still occupying memory.

After all, I unloading all textures, clearing all lists and hash maps, detaching all entities from the scene aaaaand it is still the same.

Is there any valid ways to kill that service and free memory of it?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have other LWPs of your own making that do not have this problem? If so, try creating a copy of one, then paste in the functionality of the problem LWP into it and see if it still occurs. If you don't have another of your own, you could get one from the web probably.